# Angular 6 - Execute grandparent functions from grandchild

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to execute these grandparent component functions:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public loginPage = true;

  public login = function(){
    this.loginPage = false;
  }
  public logout = function(){
    this.loginPage = true;
  }
  
}
```

from this grandchild component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropmenu',
  templateUrl: './dropmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropmenu.component.css']
})
export class DropmenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    **//EXECUTE LOGOUT() GRANDPARENT FUNCTION HERE**
  }
}
```

The closest example that I found to what I want was to create a DataService like this one:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

and then in the components do:

```
message: string;
this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
//AND
this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
```

But I don't want to pass any message, I just want to execute a function so do I really need to create that DataService? Can't I just make an Observable or something directly in the grandparent component?
If so, can someone show me an example please?

Comment: Did you already read [component interaction guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)?

Comment: You may explain your authentication strategy to comment on the specific problem. Probably you can use an authentication service and may be a guard for routes that need authentication, the guard can be configured to redirect to login page if user is not authenticated.

Comment: The authentication Im using is simple, the app.component contains the login page and the main page. The app starts with the isLoggedIn = false like so `<app-login *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"></app-login>` and if the credentials are success it changes the isLoggedIn to true and the main component is loaded like so `<app-main *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></app-main>`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I got the solution, here is what I did.

I created a DataService that receives the button click from the child and makes it observable so then the grandparent can subscribe to that subject and detect the changes and execute the grandparent function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private subject = new Subject();

    constructor() { }

    sendClickLogout() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    clickLogout(): Observable<any>{
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropmenu',
  templateUrl: './dropmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropmenu.component.css']
})
export class DropmenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout(){
    this.dataService.sendClickLogout();
  }

}
```

Grandparent component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../app/services/data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){
    this.dataService.clickLogout().subscribe(response => { this.logout() });
  }

  public loginPage = true;

  public logout = function(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.loginPage = true;
  }
}
```

I hope this to be helpful to others like me.

Comment: If you're going to have `login` / `logout` functions, put _those_ in the service, not in `AppComponent`... Maybe `AppComponent` would listen to a `loginState` observable, and display a banner or whatnot, but I don't see the reason for _it_ to actually do the logout.

Comment: Good start, but you have room for more improvement with respect to the design. But you may look at it only when you end up in another situation like this. Also try to understand why you have to use a service and how the service solved your design problem.